# Explain plan and Query execution time differences

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sql-execution-plan

I have two tables `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B` ( one to many. FK of table_a in table_b ). I have written the following 3 queries and each one of it will perform at different speeds on the tables but basically they all are doing the same.

**Time:** 3.916 seconds.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM TABLE_A hconn
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT *
  FROM TABLE_B hipconn
  WHERE HIPCONN.A_ID = HCONN.A_ID
  );
```

**Time**: 3.52 seconds

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE_A hconn,
  TABLE_B HIPCONN
WHERE HCONN.A_ID = HIPCONN.A_ID;
```

**Time**: 2.72 seconds.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE_A HCONN
JOIN TABLE_B HIPCONN
ON HCONN.A_ID = HIPCONN.A_ID;
```

From the above timings, we can know that the last query is performing better than other. (I've tested them a bunch of times and they all perform in the same order mentioned but the last query performed well always).

I've started looking at the `explain plan` for the above queries to find out why it is happening.

Query explain plan, it prints out the same `cost` and `time` for all the above queries without any difference.(Explain plan below) I re-ran a couple of times, but the result is same for all the above queries.

**Question:** Why does the speed of the results vary when the explain plan showed that it takes same amount of time for all the queries? where am I going wrong?

```
Plan hash value: 600428245

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name                           | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                                |     1 |    11 |       | 12913   (2)| 00:02:35 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                |                                |     1 |    11 |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI         |                                |  2273K|    23M|    39M| 12913   (2)| 00:02:35 |
|   3 |    INDEX STORAGE FAST FULL SCAN| BIN$ACCkNNuTHKPgUJAKNJgj5Q==$0 |  2278K|    13M|       |  1685   (2)| 00:00:21 |
|   4 |    INDEX STORAGE FAST FULL SCAN| BIN$ACCkNNubHKPgUJAKNJgj5Q==$0 |  6448K|    30M|       |  4009   (2)| 00:00:49 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("HIPCONN"."A_ID"="HCONN"."A_ID")
```

Comment: Did you change the order of query execution? Assuming all the queries running with the same value of OPTIMIZER_MODE and outlines are not used, I'd identify sql_id for each query and check what is in `v$sql` and `v$sqlarea` (I'd expect difference in one or more of ***_wait_time columns)

Comment: @a1ex07 I'm not sure what optmizer mode the db is using. I might need access to even know that, which is a big hassle to get here now :(

Comment: What happens if you take any one of those queries and execute it three times?

Comment: @mustaccio i ran the 3rd one 3 times, it gave out 3.51, 3.21, 3.20. Are you expecting anything different?

Comment: @Zeus : Check in `v$sql` - it has optimizer_mode column .

Comment: @a1ex07 as per our dba, we use cost base optmization.

Comment: I expected the execution time to follow the same patter, which I think it did.

Comment: @Zeus: for cost based optimizer you can have `ALL_ROWS` or `FIRST_ROWS`/`FIRST_ROWS_N` mode that affects execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR` to display the actual execution plan for the last SQL statement executed, since the queries may have more than one execution plan in the library cache.

Also you may enable a 10046 trace at level 12 to check why the queries are responding with different execution times.